# Discord.py move a member without mentioning a user

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make i discord bot that can move a member to a specified channel without having to mention them.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands 

token = '<token>'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='@')

@bot.command()
async def m(ctx, member : discord.Member, channel : discord.VoiceChannel):
    await member.move_to(channel)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Ready')

bot.run(token)
```

The command would be: @m @user General

This works great but i need the command to be easier to type by not having to mention a user and simply just moving the author of the message. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ctx.author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.author) and make the `member` argument optional.

Now we just move around the `member` argument to be last (because a channel  is required), and set the default value to `None` to make it optional.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def m(ctx, channel: discord.VoiceChannel, member: discord.Member = None):
    member_to_move = member or ctx.author  # if `member` is None, it will be the author instead.

    await member_to_move.move_to(channel)
```

Edit: added [`@commands.guild_only`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.guild_only) decorator. This is to ensure that the command can only be used within a guild (and will raise an error if invoked, lets say, in DMs).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ctx.author` to get the author of the message:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def m(ctx, channel : discord.VoiceChannel):
    await ctx.author.move_to(channel)
```

So, you can use the command like this: `@m General`.

Also I added `@commands.guild_only()` check to be sure that the command is invoked in the guild channel.

Comment: @Tony Then could you accept my answer, please? (if is was useful)